# TYPO3 Powermail Captcha

Tags: typo3, captcha, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

I have Upgrade my TYPO3 from 6.2.x to 7.6.15. Now in Powermail the Captcha Field doesn't work anymore. The Image is shown, but when I fill in the Code I got the Message: "Wrong Captcha". So I dig into the Code and found that in Utility.php from the Captcha Extension no `$_SESSION` is available. So there will be no Comparison. I include the Captcha Extension in Powermail via Typoscript:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.captcha.use = captcha
```

My System is:

- Powermail 3.13.0
- Captcha 2.0.1
- TYPO3 7.6.15

Answer (score 0):

You need to update powermail to their latest, currently:
Powermail to 3.18.0
Captcha to 2.0.2